# how to select data of a date which the largest of dates less than a specific date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

say I have data of multiple date and I just want to select the data of a date which is the maximum of dates smaller than a specific date.

eg.

```
id  other_columns date 
------------------------
1   ...          2020-01-12
2   ...          2019-12-31
3   ...          2019-12-31
4   ...          2019-11-01
5   ...          2019-11-01
6   ...          2018-12-21
```

for above case, if the condition is smaller than '2020-01-01', row 2 and 3 will be selected.
Since row 2 and row 3 have date just smaller than '2020-01-01'.

while if condition is smaller than '2019-12-31', then row 4 and row 5 will be selected.

I would like to see the most optimized query.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried sub-query approach. in the sub-query I get the dates less than the condition one and get the max(date) to find the maximum date, than put the date in where clause to select the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four alternatives:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM mytable m1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate
      FROM mytable
      WHERE date < '2020-01-01') m2 ON m2.maxdate = m1.date
;
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) 
              FROM mytable
              WHERE date < '2020-01-01')
;
SELECT *
FROM mytable m1
WHERE m1.date < '2020-01-01'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM mytable m2
                  WHERE m2.date > m1.date AND m2.date < '2020-01-01')
;
SELECT m1.*
FROM mytable m1
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 ON m2.date > m1.date AND m2.date < '2020-01-01'
WHERE m1.date < '2020-01-01' AND m2.id IS NULL
```

All give the same output for your sample data:

```
id  other_columns   date
2   ...             2019-12-31
3   ...             2019-12-31
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12ca19/11)

Comment: may I ask which one is the most optimized one? thanks

Comment: @kt_at_kt your mileage may vary. Best way to find out is to run them on your actual database.

Answer (score 1):

This will give your desired output.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Your_Table
WHERE date =   (
        SELECT MAX(date) 
            FROM Your_Table
        WHERE date < '2020-01-01'
        )
```